# What is the solution of the differential equation $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 -y\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 -y\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

---

I have solved a similar question and solved it very easily:
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

---

I tried to solve this other question by making $y$ the subject of the equation and then differentiating everything. I got one solution for the equation as $y=C$ and the other one was very difficult to eliminate $[y''(y'-2)=1]$. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean this in Leibniz notation, right? $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-y\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ instead by using the quadratic formula:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4y}}{2}$$
This is a separable ODE. Therefore, you can now separate variables:
$$\int \frac{2}{y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4y}}~dy=\int dx$$
After integrating both sides (You can separate the cases when the $\pm$ is a $+$ and a $-$), you should obtain two implicit solutions.